# Android: LinearLayout taking 100% of the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I would like that my chart takes 100% of the view, I just want to see the chart. I would like to remove that blank. But I'm getting this result:

[image]

And this is my `XMl` layout :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.debitdistance.WifiChartsRealTime$PlaceholderFragment" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/chart" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove all those `android:paddingXYZ` attributes from your RelativeLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the paddings from `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.debitdistance.WifiChartsRealTime$PlaceholderFragment" >

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the reason of not 100% filling the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Remove these lines:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

or change the value of `activity_horizontal_margin` and `activity_vertical_margin` to `0dp`

Answer (score 2):

The containing RelativeLayout declares padding.
set all padding values to 0dp to remove "the blank".